# English word for a "soil filter machine"?

Tags: soil, tools, rocks

Does anyone know what this machine is called in English?

It is used to put soil in, and when it turns only the fine soil comes out below and the big rocks out at the end.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Screen ,or screen drum, strainer or sieve could be used. For analysis of particle sizes in limited volume, screen sieves ( Taylor is a common name ) are commonly used.

Comment: Rotary screen, sifter...

Comment: Rotary riddle.  I don't know why they're called riddles.

Comment: To riddle in this sense means to shake or poke material so that some of it falls through a grid, grate or mesh - you riddle a fire when you use a poker, for instance. Hardly used in the UK these days as a verb or noun...